# What datastructure does google use to store its search engine indexes?

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, search-algorithms

To the best of my knowledge search engines such as Google index the web using MapReduce amongst many other tools. With my limited experience this would make hash tables the most practical option for storing the MapReduce output which by default is in the form of an inverted index.

Are hash tables in fact used by Google for storing search engine indexes or does Google use other datastructures such as binary search trees?

As a follow up question if Google uses another datastructure over hashtables what advantages does it provide?

Comment: The answer is probably proprietary.

Comment: (Without the addition of a query for suitable alternatives, this question looks [off-topic](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).)